# PHP mail() and Debian Wheezy Not Working

Tags: linux, debian, php, sendmail, exim

I am currently running my on debian wheezy with php5 installed. I was trying use the mail() function, and I realised that I will require a MTA/exim installed before it will be possible because the default installation does not come with any.

I was looking at a solution at: https://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4

However, it says that This setting is for a typical desktop PC which has no resolvable host name.

Are there any good references for the settings I can use for a hosting server?

Comment: Do you just  want this server to just be able to send mail or act as a mail server?

Comment: @slm i just want it to be able to send mails.

Comment: If you're only intending to send mails from the server then you don't need a mail server, just a client and access to external servers.

Comment: @slm While I was trying to find a solution to this problem, it seems that google compute engine oes not allow emails to be sent out through port 25. https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail, perhaps that is the issue I am facing. Do you happen to know if there's anyway I can circumvent this issue without having the need to register with their partner site for additional service?

Comment: No sorry I'm not aware of anything.